# why findAll in bs4 didnt work with dict who have double atribute argument?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, findall

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZbbR.png)
Learning bs4 and findAll() didnt work with dict and with two atribute tag. Where is mistake? Cause it return only 'green' tag and no 'red'.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.error import HTTPError
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/warandpeace.html'

def get_title(URL):
    try:
        html = urlopen(URL)
    except HTTPError as e:
        return None
    try:
        bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
        namelist = bsObj.findAll('span', {'class':'green', 'class':'red'})
    except AttributeError as e:
        return None
    return namelist
namelist = get_title(URL)
if namelist == None:
    print('we cant take title')
else:
    for name in namelist:
        print(name.get_text())
```

Comment: A Python dictionary can only hold one value per key.

Comment: but this is an example from a book Web Scraping with Python O'nelly page 35

Comment: Then this is an error in the book.

Comment: The GitHub for this book does not show the 'class': 'red' entry: https://github.com/REMitchell/python-scraping/blob/master/Chapter02-AdvancedHTMLParsing.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

You can import the `re` module and use the following:

```py
import re

namelist = bsObj.findAll('span', {'class': re.compile(r"green|red")})
```

Comment: ty, its help and work, but didnt know what im doing wrong with book example that its not working

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, the method just doesn't work. It's an error in the book. Dictionaries can't hold more than one value for a key in python, that's by definition